# Jupyter Kernel connection error: Path not found

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter-notebook

When I try to launch a notebook the kernel can't connect and return this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'path' from 'IPython.external.path' (C:\Users\u557210\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\path\__init__.py)
```

Where could I find this path package? Or how to fix this error ?

Cheers

Comment: Which version of ipython are you using? Try upgrading it.